# High-school group-theory problem(given in a contest)

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, contest-math

Let $G$ be a finite group and let $ H \le G $ be a subgroup of $G$. 
Suppose there is some $ \emptyset \neq S \subset G$ such that for any $x\in S$ we have $x^2 \notin H$. Prove that there is $T \subset S$ with $|T|\ge \frac{|S|}{2}$ and such that for any $a,b \in T$ we have $ab\notin H$ or $ba \notin H$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $T$ be a subset of $S$ that has the required property ${\mathbf P}:a,b \in T \Rightarrow ab \not\in H$ or $ba \not\in H$, and is not properly contained in any larger such subset. The condition $x^2 \not\in H$ for all $x \in S$ ensures that single element subsets satisfy${\mathbf P}$, so $T$ is nonempty.

We claim that $S \setminus T$ also satisfies ${\mathbf P}$. If not, then there exist $a,b \in S \setminus T$ with $ab,ba \in H$. Since neither $T \cup \{a\}$ nor $T \cup \{b\}$  satisfies ${\mathbf P}$, there exist $c,d \in T$ with $ac,ca,bd,db \in H$.

But then $cd = (ca)(ba)^{-1}(bd)$ and $dc = (db)(ab)^{-1}(ac)$ are in $H$, contradicting the assumption that $T$ satisfies ${\mathbf P}$.

This contradiction proves that $S \setminus T$ satisfies ${\mathbf P}$, and at least one of $T$ and $S \setminus T$ must have size at least $|S|/2$.

Note that this does not assumme that $G$ is finite, only that $S$ is finite.